# try_files with custom location ^/([0-9]+)

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-location

am trying to run location with same rule of rewrite

nginx rewrite

```
rewrite ^/([0-9]+)$ /post.php?id=$1 ;
```

not working with

```
location ~ ^/([0-9]+) {
try_files /s.php-$1.txt /s.php?page=$1 ;
root   /home/XX/public_html;
types {}
default_type text/html;
}
```

it's working good if i add any word like ^/S([0-9]+)

but without *S* this rule damage all images and others urls

Comment: Only the first regex ends with a `$`.

Comment: i found idea , hope it's a good one , i set answers @RichardSmith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had a years trying to fix it , with no hope

today , i found idea when see way of 404 with custom location

```
error_page   500 502 503 504 404  /custom.html;
location = /custom.html {
try_files /cachep/index.txt /index.php ;
root   /home/xxx/public_html;
types {}
default_type text/html;
}
```

so what , if rewrite working good

we will use it with location with same way

```
rewrite ^/([0-9]+)$ /T$1 ;

location ~ /T([0-9]+) {
try_files /cachep/$1.html /post.php?id=$1 ;
root   /home/xxx/public_html;
expires max;
types {}
default_type text/html;
}
```

i use

```
types {}
default_type text/html;
```

to make txt file viewing like html

i hope one day any one search for same problem
Found it